# Remover UI Debugging Tools da Janela

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, debug, uwp

Gostaria de saber como remover a opção `UI Debugging Tools for XAML` que aparece no topo da janela `WPF` (conforme imagem abaixo)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desmarque a opção:

`Tools` ⇢ `Options` ⇢ `Debugging` ⇢ `General` ⇢ `Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[**Fonte**](http://developerpublish.com/disable-ui-debugging-tools-for-xaml-in-visual-studio-2015/)